# php regex and possibly using (?<!a)b within my own regex

Tags: php, regex

Trying to work on a PHP regex that will match words that may be functions, that are not in double quotes. While ignoring anything that is in double quotes that may be functions. The below already matches 'hello(world)'. And will place 'hello(world)' in one array then 'hello' in another. However, I want to have a conditional that does not add it as stated above.

```
preg_match_all('#(\w*)\s*\(.*?\)#i',$str,$m);
```

I was trying to play with it. And using the following example to help me.

```
(?<!a)b
```

Though the pattern turns out wrong when applied. If anyone has any help in the matter, I would appreciate it.

As a output of the current design of the regex. Take the following example.

**Input:**

one($two) two($1) three($2one)}meme1(you2) this(that) die ("now") these function myfunc($me) empty()

**Output:**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'one($two)',
    1 => 'two($1)',
    2 => 'three($2one)',
    3 => 'meme1(you2)',
    4 => 'this(that)',
    5 => 'die (\\"meohmy\\")',
    6 => 'myfunc($me)',
    7 => 'empty()',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
    2 => 'three',
    3 => 'meme1',
    4 => 'this',
    5 => 'die',
    6 => 'myfunc',
    7 => 'empty',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Strip out double quotes (with content) beforehand. Better yet use the tokenizer, or PHP_Parser; that's more exact (or less effort) than a regex for finding function names.

Comment: @mario I think you may have negated the fact that I am not looking to strip out the quoted lines. Only overlook them. Which if I can figure out how to use (?<!a)b. Can be done. And it is not a duplication of the aforementioned link. In simplicity I have a simple script language designed in another language .. lsl for Second Life. This regex is suppose to scan for key commands from that lsl while not trying to process it. Just to check that its valid in or out of quotes. Using the PHP_Parser to determine simplistic is or is not in quotes will make the end design bulky.

Comment: You're not supposed to throw the original content away, but make a *temporary copy* sans double quoted stuff, then run your regex. You can't have arbitrary-length lookbehinds with PCRE. You are looking to exclude `print "text notafunction(123) there";` right? That could only work with assertions if the string isn't multiline etc.

Comment: @mario And ultimately unneeded when as stated if someone with better understanding of (?<!a)b. Could tell me how to work that in. Would suffice.

Comment: @mario How can I put this in better words. My original regex works perfectly for my needs. It has done its work on that simple base. So pushing it into complexity is a scope thats unneeded for the end means. Oh well will keep seeing how to put (?<!a)b into an applicable context for that regex. Everything else is done in the lsl processor script for the game I have designed. All I need is something to determine is or is not in quotes. Thank you though.

Comment: @mario To add to my above comment. No one has access to the way codes get pushed in our out of the game. Well they shouldn't -heh- This is simply a design structure I wish to add in for myself when polling data. So nothing will be multiline =) Well okay maybe in some case where I might think it looks better multiline. Then that would be something to look at.

Comment: Which part of your example input/output demonstrates the double-quotes requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, you can't have arbitrary-length lookbehind. What you can have however, is arbitrary-length lookahead. Just as - I think - you wanted to have a lookbehind to count the ", you can count those who come after. Something along the lines of:

```
/(\w+)\s*\(.*?\)(?=(?:[^"]|".*?")*$)/
```

However:
- Be sure you apply this on well formated code
- If would be fooled by an escaped " (you can fix that, I don't have the courage atm)
- I didn't bother looking at the performance, so you may have some work here

Overall, this may not be a good idea.

**Edit:**
What does it do? I took your regex, and added a check after your matchs. **Each time** it finds a match, it will check until the end of the string that there is a pair number of " (extremely inefficient against a large string).

A more efficient way? Sure. The fact that you can't catch an undefined number of groups in a regex is a bother. It means you'll have to loop through your string. Basically, use preg_match with all its arguments (get the position of the match in the 'matches' array thanks to the 4th argument (see the [preg_match doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)) and loop with the 5th), and with something like this:

```
/(?:[^"]|".*?")*?(\w+)\s*\(.*?\)/
```

(as I'm writing this, I'm thinking that it's not that efficient either, but is still better against large strings.)
(note: I didn't test it as I'm extremely sleepy, if you're satisfied with either solutions, close the question, if not, I'll be back anyway)

Comment: To be completely honest within the structure of what I was wanting to do this worked perfectly. Like a charm. So much appreciated. I am still learning about regex so while I understand some of it when sectioned. Trying to see how it pieced it in your work. That way I can know how to do it myself in better detail then to be stumped. I was using http://www.functions-online.com as a tool. And the work I am doing is all being passed to a script myself. So no one should be adding bad data. Uness I do something myself thats silly.

Comment: As for escaping data. All data is being escaped before it hits the regex. Which I am hoping that works well enough. I have voted this as best answer as it was what I was wanting. Even if I may have seemed a bit unclear. So thank you kindly again.

Comment: What I meant about the escaped part is: *"I'm a string with a \" lololol" would fool it.

Comment: Also tested the regex against the full input thats being done. Its a basic game but wanted a one line regex. I know it was possible with a few lines. Though I like one line solutions if they can do whats needed. Between the server <> client the response was .2 seconds in overall command processing. The pulled in test file was 1 MB. And was using a PHP server contacting a LSL object within SecondLife.

Comment: Yeah as it could also imply a lookbehind, as you'd have to see if the " has no \ before it. (but the \ could have a \ before and so on... god dammit I need sleep, have fun ;))

Comment: LOL thanks a lot for the help even if you are sleepy. It has helped.

Comment: To give you an idea on how it was being applied. I have done a bit of coding work before but never much with regex. Though all the other ways I looked at were lengthier. And here comes my desire to apply a regex to the solution. The game integrates with a inventory system, player, game, world. Passing commands from in-game to the PHP and back. I just needed a simple way to observe when things were in and out of quotes. What reason? So that I could pass functions between objects without it being called.

Comment: For example say I was having things communicate. And this is only an example. If say the inventory system passed commands to player. But had a relay attached to send also to the game. The quotes would allow player to exec the commands its allowed. And then say it would pass the rest on to world. Then the world would construct a preprocessor with the quoted commands. Then generate a new exec.

Comment: But thats only an example. It may seem ineffective when noted here. Though in any other processing way my work would not well "work".